# What was the reason for the Night Watch men's treatment of Jon Snow?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* season 5 episode 10 *Mother's Mercy*, the watchmen at Castle Black lure Jon Snow outside and lead him to a sign with the word *traitor* painted on it where a group of mutineers are waiting, and they stab him repeatedly in the abdomen. These mutineers are enraged at Snow's orders to allow the wildlings through the wall.

If they're so opposed to his plan to allow the wildlings through the wall, why didn't they simply refuse to open the gate for him when he returned to the wall with the wildlings? They could have prevented the outcome they opposed rather than merely taking revenge on Jon Snow after it was already too late to stop the wildlings from crossing.

Comment: Possibly they assumed that he'd fail in his task and would be killed by the wildlings, making his return a bit of a surprise, so they fell back on following orders as they usually do.  Plus, the killing of John Snow wasn't a unanimous thing.  They isolated him and confronted him in a group of conspirators-only, which was not the case with the makeup of those on the wall when he came back.